# How to replace quotation marks with angle brackets between two patterns recursively for all file in a directory with sed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sed

The repository I am working on has multiple source files in a non-flat directory structure, e.g.

```
project
│   main.cpp
│
└───moduleA
    │   A.cpp
```

All these source files have code something like

```
#include "A.h"

WINDOWS_DISABLE_WARNING
#include "externalA.h"
#include "externalB.h"
WINDOWS_ENABLE_WARNING

// more code
```

How can I use `sed` to replace all quotation marks include with angle brackets include between `WINDOWS_DISABLE_WARNING` macro and `WINDOWS_ENABLE_WARNING` macro for all files like below recursively?

```
#include "A.h"

WINDOWS_DISABLE_WARNING
#include <externalA.h>
#include <externalB.h>
WINDOWS_ENABLE_WARNING

// more code
```

I know how to replace simple strings recursively like `find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/oldtext/newtext/' {} \;`, but I am struggling to figure out how to replace quotation marks with angle brackets between two patterns.

The reason I am doing is this is because [Visual Studio recently introduced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/external-external-headers-diagnostics?view=msvc-170) `/external:anglebrackets`, if this flag is enabled, any headers included with angle brackets are treated as external, and the warnings coming from it can be turned off via `/external:W0`. That means no more ugly macros like `WINDOWS_DISABLE_WARNING` which is defined as `__pragma(warning(push,0))` if on Windows, otherwise empty, via CMake's `target_compile_definitions` and similarly `WINDOWS_ENABLE_WARNING` which is defined as `__pragma(warning(pop))` if on Windows, otherwise empty, via CMake's `target_compile_definitions`. Since using `sed` to remove the macros recursively is pretty straightforward, eventually the code can become clean like the below when working with loosely written third-party libraries with the new `/external` flags enabled.

```
#include "A.h"

#include <externalA.h>
#include <externalB.h>

// more code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [addressing lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/sed-addresses.html#sed-addresses) in sed

```sh
find ... -exec sed -i '/WINDOWS_DISABLE_WARNING/,/WINDOWS_ENABLE_WARNING/ { s/"/</; s/"/>/ }' '{}' +
```

Make sure to back your files up (`sed -i.bak`) (or omit the `-i` option) before experimenting with `-i`

Comment: I tried your command but I got `find: ‘...’: No such file or directory`

Comment: that's not a complete find command. you need to specify the criteria needed to find your files. Suggestion: don't cut-and-paste code you find on the internet unless you understand what it's going to do to your system.

Comment: Replacing `...` to `./ -type f` runs, but it does nothing. Can you let us know the correct command or explain to us your answer so we can understand it and debug it?

Comment: The first step is to manually select a single file, then run the sed command (without -i) on it and see if the change occurs as expected.